# Ambiguous routing exception in gRPC .NET 5 / C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, grpc, .net-5

I've created my 1st gRPC App in .NET5, using Grpc.AspNetCore and protobuf-net nugets.

Initially all my service methods were synchronous. At this stage client-server communication functioned well.

Then I found that I need async support too, and added an async equivalent for each existing method, like:

```
AssemblyNamesDto GetAssemblyNamesFromFiles(MyDto payload);
Task<AssemblyNamesDto> GetAssemblyNamesFromFilesAsync(MyDto payload);
```

Since I've done this I get Exceptions on the server side with the message:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints.

If I rename the Async "overload" to something like `GetAssemblyNamesFromFiles2Async`, the `AmbiguousMatchException` goes away.

So my assumption is that there is generated code somewhere that makes pairs of synchronous and asynchronous method names implicitly.

Adding "Async" at the the end of the synchronous method name and vice versa.

I've seen this in WCF-REST projects that method pairs like this are are generated automatically.

So my question is: if the `async` methods are generated automatically, how can I use them?

I can't find generated code files in the project.

Or: how can I somehow solve the routing ambiguity issue by e.g. adding `[Route]` attributes or by other means?

I used the gRPC project template of VS 2019.

I didn't add any routing attributes. The service just implements the service interface methods, which have no overloads with same name.
The project is not ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: You can try to use `[Route("GetAssemblyNamesFromFiles")]` and `[Route("GetAssemblyNamesFromFilesAsync")]`.

Comment: @Yiyu You Thx for the tip. But it didn't do the trick, unfortunately. The Routing table seems to be generated by the protobuf-net API in Grpc/Protobuf-net context.

Here someone has a similar problem: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net.Grpc/issues/152

As a workaround, I simply removed the non-async methods now.

But still would like to know how to explicitly declare routing paths in this context.